# Unable to get json data from show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get the json data that has been rendered on my show page  onto the new.html.erb and unfortunately no matter how I am doing it the data is not getting displayed and I get an error saying `GET http://localhost:3000/posts/posts/1 404 (Not Found)`. I notice that I am making a get for`posts/1' but it looks for 'posts/posts/1'

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'posts/1',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(posts){
   console.log("yes", posts);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to your url to look like: `'/posts/1'`if you  don't put the "/" in the jquery will append it to your current location.

Comment: Thanks Cam. Though I am making a request at '/posts/1' the datas are not getting displayed even in console.log.

Comment: Never mind. Got it actually. I used` .done ` instead of success. Not sure why I was able to console log it with `.done`. If anyone reads this I will be interested to know.

Comment: Without seeing anything my only guess would be that your response wasn't returning a 200 response. Success will only fire with the response status. Done will be called no matter what the response status